# Get latest and earliest value of different column from same table sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, self-join, having

I have a table with a selection of dates. I want to be able to apply a WHERE statement to return a group of them and then return which date is the earliest from one column and which one is the latest from another column. Here is an example table:

```
ID  StartDate   EndDate     Person   Subject
1   01/03/2010  03/03/2010   Paul    Math
2   12/05/2010  22/05/2010   Steve   Science
3   04/03/2010  08/03/2010   Paul    English
```

So I want to return all the records where Person = 'Paul'. But return something like (earliest ) StartDate = 01/03/2010 (from record ID 1) and (latest) EndDate = 08/03/2010 (from record ID 3) and Subject = English  from  latest EndDate (from record 3 ). I need two rows for Paul with the above data and Id.Need all row with person = 'Paul'

Expected Result :

```
ID  StartDate   EndDate Person  Subject
1   2010-03-01  2010-03-08  Paul    English
3   2010-03-01  2010-03-08  Paul    English
```

Do you see any problem regarding performance (Millions of records) in below sql query  :

```
 Select PT3.ID,PT4.EarliestStartDate AS StartDate,PT4.EndDate,PT4.Person,PT4.Subject from Data AS PT3 
Join( SELECT Top 1 with ties * FROM Data AS PT  
Join( SELECT PT1.Person as Person1, MIN(PT1.StartDate ) as EarliestStartDate FROM Data AS PT1 where Person ='Paul' group by PT1.Person)  AS PT2 ON  PT.Person =PT2.Person1WHERE Person  ='Paul'
  Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By PT.Person Order By PT.EndDate desc)) AS PT4 ON PT3.Person = PT4.Person
```

Comment: please show your query

Comment: Sounds like `group by ' and min/max.

Comment: So you want to get the earliest start date and the latest end date regardless of subject? Then seperately just get the subject of the latest end date?

Comment: What is the expected result ?

Comment: @avinashkadu I assume the start date `04/03/2101` is a typo? Otherwise the corresponding end date would come before the start date...

Comment: Your latest edit just changed the question entirely... Can you explain why you need 2 rows to avoid any kind of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)? And what are your criteria for the `ID` column in the result? If there was one row with both the smallest start date _and_ the latest end date, would you want to see that row id twice?

Comment: (1) That still does not answer how the `ID` column must be determined... The Id of the minimum start date row, the Id of the maximum end date row, the minimum and maximum of the ids, ... ? What if row 3 also contained the smallest start date? (2) You now changed the question _again_ to a performance related question this time. Please do not mix result questions with performance questions (_first_ make it work, _then_ make it work fast). Ask separate questions for each part.

Comment: For two  ID there will not  the smallest start date and the latest end date

Comment: What is the intention of the `with ties` in your query? This can give you more than 2 output rows with your query: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=48c63a7bf9d0e02c893ae8380e29e045).

Comment: Need all row with person = 'Paul'

Comment: @avinashkadu, You might want to include that important fact in your question. Now the `self-join` tag makes sense too. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
@Sander What about the performance? Do you have any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work:

1. Perform the `group by` first to get the required dates for each person.
2. Move the grouping to a common table expression (`cte`).
3. Join back with the full data set to fetch all rows.
4. For each result record, select the corresponding subject with a `cross apply`.
5. Optional: filter on the required person (`where` clause).

**Sample data**

```
create table Data
(
  ID int,
  StartDate date,
  EndDate date,
  Person nvarchar(10),
  Subject nvarchar(10)
);

insert into Data (ID, StartDate, EndDate, Person, Subject) values
(1, '2010-03-01', '2010-03-03', 'Paul',  'Math'),
(2, '2010-05-12', '2010-05-22', 'Steve', 'Science'),
(3, '2010-03-04', '2010-03-08', 'Paul',  'English');
```

**Solution**

```
with cte as
(
  select min(d.StartDate) as StartDate,
         max(d.EndDate) as EndDate,
         d.Person
  from Data d
  group by d.Person
)
select d.Id,
       c.StartDate,
       c.EndDate,
       c.Person,
       x.Subject
from cte c
join data d
  on d.Person = c.Person
cross apply ( select top 1 d2.Subject
              from Data d2
              where d2.Person = c.Person
                and d2.EndDate = c.EndDate ) x
where d.Person = 'Paul'
order by d.Person;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e5197e68a65290c190c377614f80fee5) to see it in action.

Comment: I have added the expected result and my  query

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the right values.

```
DECLARE @values TABLE (
    Id INT,
    StartDate DATETIME2,
    EndDate DATETIME2,
    Person NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Subject NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @values VALUES 
(1, '2010-03-01', '2010-03-03', 'Paul', 'Math'),
(2, '2010-05-12', '2010-05-22', 'Steve', 'Science'),
(3, '2101-03-04', '2010-03-08', 'Paul', 'English')

;WITH sort AS (
    SELECT
        Person,
        MIN(StartDate) OVER(PARTITION BY Person) StartDate,
        MAX(EndDate) OVER(PARTITION BY Person) EndDate,
        Subject,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY EndDate DESC) rownum
    FROM @values v)

SELECT
    Person,
    StartDate,
    EndDate,
    Subject
FROM sort
WHERE rownum = 1
```

It will give you the following result:

```
Person  MinStartDate    MaxEndDate   Subject
Paul    2010-03-01      2010-03-08   English
Steve   2010-05-12      2010-05-22   Science
```

Comment: Your current version does not solve the `Subject` part of the question.

Comment: @Kristofer how can I get all Id of paul as well with the same result set of your query (other column value will be same)?

Answer (score 0):

This should be sufficient if you only care about selecting Pauls data:

```
SELECT 
   Person,
   MIN(startDate) AS Earliest, 
   MAX(EndDate) AS Latest, 
   (
      SELECT TOP 1 Subject 
      FROM Data
      WHERE Person = 'Paul'
      ORDER BY EndDate DESC
   ) AS Subject
FROM Data WHERE Person = 'Paul'
```

And this should work if you want to select all persons:

```
SELECT 
   d1.Person,
   MIN(d1.startDate) AS Earliest, 
   MAX(d1.EndDate) AS Latest, 
   (
      SELECT TOP 1 d2.Subject 
      FROM Data d2
      WHERE d2.Person = d1.Person
      ORDER BY EndDate DESC
   ) AS Subject
FROM Data d1
GROUP BY d1.Person
```

Edit: You seem to want to have results for every row in the table, instead of just one per person, but then always show the earliest and latest dates. Is this what your after?

```
SELECT 
   d1.Id,
   d1.Person,
   (
      SELECT MIN(d1.StartDate) AS Earliest
      FROM Data d2
      WHERE d2.Person = d1.Person
   ) AS Earliest,
   (
      SELECT MAX(d1.EndDate) AS Latest
      FROM Data d2
      WHERE d2.Person = d1.Person
   ) AS Latest,
   (
      SELECT TOP 1 d2.Subject 
      FROM Data d2
      WHERE d2.Person = d1.Person
      ORDER BY EndDate DESC
   ) AS Subject
FROM Data d1
```

Comment: Your answer does not contain valid SQL syntax (hint: the literal string `Paul` needs quotes).

Comment: @Sander I Fixed it and also added the Person column to the result

Comment: @Fuzzy I have updated the question with the expected result